# Ubuntu Server for Pakistan

Tags: server, software-center, ubiquity

I am from Pakistan and have installed ubuntu fresh copy and deleted the previous one. Now in the ubiquity installer I set my location to Pakistan and the server was set to .pk server of ubuntu by the installer itself which I think is down. Whenever I run updates it gives a 404 error that the server was not found. I can not install any software because it gives errors "broken packages". I tried to change server location from pakistan to usa in the software center but the error persisted. Now I installed again and set my location as New York in the ubiquity installer, it is good now. I have two questions:

1. If server for Pakistan is down then why it is included in installer because it damages the whole install.
2. Now, if I set my location back to Pakistan, will the server location change itself? If yes, then How should I set my time, location etc. to Pakistan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repos are not directly owned/manged by Ubuntu but other third-parties and hence it is not Ubuntu who is responsible for updating these servers. You can set the system to fetch packages from other working servers and this is usually not at all a problem and will not affect your time-zones etc (which you can set yourself independent of what repo you use to get packages)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just confused. Now I am going to set my location and I will also modify the ubiquity installer to set the server location to USA whenever I install a new copy of ubuntu. Once again, Thanks alot.

Comment: Here The tick goes, but I thought I may get some more answers with more details.